# how do I specify a system font that handles wide characters on the iphone?

Tags: iphone, text, system, fonts

This is sort of a generic question due to my lack of experience with fonts, so a little patience and/or pointing in the right direction to get more info would be appreciated.  I have an iphone app and am noticing that when I print some text on my labels, I end up with garbage when the string contains non-ascii, like Korean for example.

My guess is that since my UILabels, for instance, are using the system font, perhaps the system font does not support displaying wide characters.  However, I'm left with a few beginner questions:

1) How do I set the system font so my iphone sdk objects that use the system font use it?

2) Does this sound correct that the system font probably doesn't support wide characters and is the reason I see garbage when I have characters out of the normal ascii range?

Thanks.  Let me know if I need to clarify the problem please.

Update:
I later suspected maybe it was a problem on my server end so posted this related but not identical post here: [does google app engine display unicode differently in StringProperty v StringListProperty objs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3091034/does-google-app-engine-display-unicode-differently-in-stringproperty-v-stringlist)

Comment: It is more likely that you are not using the correct string encoding.  Where is the text coming from and what encoding would you expect it to have?  What methods are you using to create strings from the text?

Comment: I will update the original post with some additional info on the server end.

Comment: To answer your question more directly, I am forming a python string on the server by appending a variable that is Korean text.  Perhaps I am not calling s.encode or s.decode correctly?  I don't call either of these and am a bit confused by which I should be calling, if so.  On the client end, I use CFURLCreateStringByReplacingPercentEscapes() to remove the percent escapes.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the problem was not with the font, but with improperly encoding the data response from the server into Ascii when I should have used UTF8.  It appears the font supported unicode to begin with.